# Make a div active without clicking somewhere in it

Tags: html, css

I use a horizontal scroll on a page I built. It's inside a div, named it with a class, and I want to use the arrows keys to scroll. For it to scroll with the keys, I need to click somewhere on it.

Is it possible to use the keys directly on first load of the page without necessarily clicking it?

I need the arrow keys to be functional directly and start the horizontal scroll inside that particular div, if that's possible.

```css
.scroll { grid-template-columns: repeat(15,1fr); overflow-x: scroll; scroll-snap-type: x proximity; }
```

```html
<ul class="scroll"> <div class="container"> <img src="ok.png"> <div class="inmiddle"> <div class="description"> blablabla</div> </div> </div></li></ul>
```

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: What have you already tried? Show us your code.

Comment: Not here, edit the question.

Comment: Added elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you can just use this simple JS:

```js
document.getElementById('scroll').focus();
```

```html
<body> 
  <div id="scroll">
    example      
  </div> 
</body>
```

Otherwise add the pseudo class `:active` to your div.

You can also change the properties to this pseudo class as you need.

[Useful documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Comment: Hello. Doesn't work for me. It's still not active and I need to hover/click the div for arrows to work.

Comment: <body>
<div id=scroll>insert horizontal scroll here but doesn't take the whole page just a witdh of 500px and height of 100px somewhere</div>
</body>

It will only scroll with the keys when I click on the div.

Comment: `<body> <div id="scroll" class="current" ></div> </body>` and in the css put something like this `scroll.current`

Comment: Are you using Javascript? Bcs if you want I've also a solution that involves some javascript but that is really easy

Comment: I thank you for your time and help. Unfortunately, I have 0 knowledge in JS. I tried the scroll.current to no avail.

Comment: If you wuold try to use JS, just include the library of js in the header and use this `document.getElementById('scroll').focus();`

Comment: Forgive my incompetence, doesn't do anything. I also get an error for document unnamed or something.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to listen to your keys via `addEventListener` ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values 
You can check the key values from this website.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I should be sorry, I didn't check the tags properly. It's about JavaScript.
If you're using JS, you can listen to your keys and whenever they're clicked you can go to next scroll

Comment: I have 0 knowledge of JS unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry again, I didn't check properly.